# Show zero as a different character in bar graph. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics, graph, matlab-figure

I am trying to make a simple bar graph in MATLAB and whenever the value is zero I want to put a character there. Like an asterisk or something to show that the value for that bar is zero. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you're asking.  Do you want to place something in the column where the bar has 0 height instead of nothing?  Can you show us an example of what it is you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
data = [3.1 4.5 0 6.3 2.7 0 6.1]; %// example data
H = -.008; %// horizontal offset relative to axis span. Set as needed
V = .03; %// vertical offset relative to axis span. Set as needed

h = bar(data); %// plot data
xdata = get(h, 'XData'); %// get x data from plot
ydata = get(h, 'YData'); %// get y data from plot
ind = ydata==0; %// logical index of zero-height data
xl = xlim; %// span of x axis
yl = ylim; %// span if y axis
hoffset = xl(1)+xl(2)*H; %// compute horizontal offset
voffset = yl(1)+yl(2)*V; %// compute vertical offset
text(xdata(ind)+hoffset, repmat(voffset,1,sum(ind)), '*', 'fontsize', 12) %// create text
```

[image]

Comment: Nice job. _I wish these kind of posters would come back to give feedback_